# How to check if a transaction is pending?

Tags: web3js, pending-transactions

I tried to send a signedTransaction using a low gas price (it's my will to test timeoute of my scripts)

I supposed also that a not mined transaction was 'pending', so I tried checking, while the first transaction has not been mined yet, using

```
web3.eth.getPendingTransactions();
```

I got every time an empty array.

Why?

So, what is a pending transaction?

Answer (score 1):

This function returns all pending transactions in a node's mempool, but it doesn't work in Web3.js.

To read a node's mempool using Web3.js, you need to add a custom call -

```
//add txpool support
web3.extend({
   property: 'txpool',
   methods: [{
      name: 'content',
      call: 'txpool_content'
   }]
})
```

Then call it -

```
web3.txpool.content((err, data) => {
   console.log(err, data)
});
```

If you want to check a specific transaction status, you can use [`web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(txHash)`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html#gettransactionreceipt), if you get `null`, that transaction wasn't mined yet (still pending).

Answer (score 1):

`web3.eth.getPendingTransactions();` returns an empty array because it's supposed to only return the transactions originating from an account on the node itself (not all pending transactions). Check [source](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/ead814616c094331915b03edd82d4200a7880178/internal/ethapi/api.go#L1700).

Good explanation [here too](https://chainstack.com/exploring-the-methods-of-looking-into-ethereums-transaction-pool/).